# How to add tiles provided by other providers in folium?

Tags: python, folium

Here's My Code:

```
import folium as fo
map = fo.Map( [28.908099854138516, 76.59597016811227] , tiles= , zoom_start=11 , )
```

Here, i want to add this tile:
[Tile Which I want to add](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/#filter=Thunderforest.SpinalMap)

How can i add this to my Code

Answer (score 1):

To set a [custom tile](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/TilesExample.ipynb), you need to set the attributes and specify the tile. You will also need an API key, so please register at [thunderforest.com](https://www.thunderforest.com/docs/map-tiles-api/) to get one.

```
import folium

lat, lon = 28.908099854138516, 76.59597016811227
zoom_start = 5

attr = '&copy; <a href="http://www.thunderforest.com/">Thunderforest</a>, &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'

#apikey = open('./thunderforest_api_key.txt').read()
tiles = 'https://tile.thunderforest.com/spinal-map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

m = folium.Map(location=[lat, lon], tiles=tiles, attr=attr, zoom_start=zoom_start)

m
```

[image]